# Упаковать jre в exe launch4j

Tags: java, exe

Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать так: Положить jre в отдельную папку, в launch4j указать путь к этой папке и чтобы при запуске exe-файла jre бралась оттуда, а не искалась на компьютере?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553161/4444092

Comment: @Tsyklop да, я так пробовал, не работает